# RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log while calculating cost in DNN

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, gradient-descent

This is the code of neural network with one output layer:

```
    features = ['Pclass' , 'Age' , 'Sex']
    X = dataset[features]

    dataset['Survived'] = dataset['Survived']
    y = dataset[['Survived']]

    label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
    transform_sex = array(X['Sex'])
    fit_sex = label_encoder.fit_transform(transform_sex)
    X['Sex'] = fit_sex

    def para(dim):
        W = np.random.randn(dim,1)*0.01
        b = 0
        return W , b
    W , b = para(3)

    def propagate(W , b , X , Y):
        m = X.shape[1]

        Z = np.add(X.dot(W),b)
        A = expit(Z.values)

        cost = -((Y.T.dot(np.log(A)) + (1-Y).T.dot(np.log(1-A)))/m)

        dw = (np.dot(X.T , np.subtract(A,y)))/m
        db = np.sum(np.subtract(A,y))/m

        cost = np.squeeze(cost)
        grads = {
                "dw" : dw ,
                "db" : db }
        return grads , cost , A , Z

    def optimize(W , b , X , y , iter , rate):
        costs = []
        for i in range(iter):
            grads , cost , A , Z = propagate(W , b , X , y)

            dw = grads["dw"]
            db = grads["db"]
            W = W - dw*rate
            b = b - db*rate

            if i % 20 == 0:
                costs.append(cost)
                print("cost after itr" , i , "is: " , cost)

        params = {
                    "W" : W ,
                    "b" : b }
        grads = {"dw" : dw,
                 "db" : db
                }
        return params , grads , costs

    params , grads , costs = optimize(W , b , X , y , 5000 , 0.01)
```

X , Y is train data.

For just one iteration , cost = 218.50432251902964 and then I am getting runtime warning. And after 1 iteration , my cost is retuned as nan. For few iterations , cost value is returned and then again nan. This is the output:

```
    cost after itr 0 is:  218.50432251902964
    1l.py:40: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
      cost = -((Y.T.dot(np.log(A)) + (1-Y).T.dot(np.log(1-A)))/m)
      cost after itr 20 is:  nan
      cost after itr 40 is:  nan
      cost after itr 60 is:  nan
      cost after itr 80 is:  nan
      cost after itr 100 is:  nan
      cost after itr 120 is:  21440.69512895518
      cost after itr 140 is:  nan
      cost after itr 160 is:  nan
      cost after itr 180 is:  nan
```

Comment: Your `y_hat` values are either <0 or >1. It's hard to tell how to prevent that, as not much code is provided.

Comment: t_hat is not the predicted output. Here y_hat is the last activation output of the layer i.e A.

Comment: Now, you're introducing t_hat and A, which do not appear the main post. Please clarify your question. It's hard to parse all this information. It would be best if you could provide [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: my bad. it's not t_hat , it is y_hat . And y_hat and A are same. A is the activation output of the last output layer ( It is probability and not the predicted outcome in terms of 0/1. It can vary bet 0 and 1.)

Comment: I also tried the same thing with one output layer.  Cost at 1 iteration is 205.98  and nan afterwards .   Z = np.add(X.dot(W),b) , A = expit(Z) , cost = -((Y.T.dot(np.log(A)) + (1-Y).T.dot(np.log(1-A)))/m) This is my 1 output layer implementation . where m = X.shape[1] .   Also , there is an extra 0 in A when I print A but dimension is correct i.e. (891,1) .

Comment: If you keep posting more code in comments and don't edit your original post (clarifying it), then I bet you'll get 0 answers.

Comment: I have edited the question completely . Now if it may be clear  to find the issue.

Comment: There is more information now, but still the code is not reproducible (see previous link from me). It's hard to help.

Comment: Please see now.

Comment: Now your code is longer, but is not __reproducible__. I have no idea what `dataset` should be in order to reproduce it. It also seems for me that the code is not minimal. Imports are missing, etc. I suggest monitoring what `A` is.

Comment: dataset is 'Titanic'  from kaggle .

Comment: Still, this is not enough to reproduce. I bet there are many ways one can load "'Titanic' from kaggle." I suggest you start at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Once more, I suggest you look at `A` that produces the problem and try to build minimal reproducible example (see link from yesterday; MRE). I bet one can built a few line long MRE by setting `A`, `Y`, and `m` and  then calculating `cost`.